# Copy root folder to docker root path?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to copy **/data/resources/config** directory to docker image.

```
FROM java:latest
WORKDIR /tmp
MAINTAINER Service
COPY target/Service-1.3.jar .

RUN mkdir -p /data/resources

COPY /data/resources/config /data/resources

...
```

I'm getting  error :

> COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder047879799/data/resources/config: no such file or directory

How I can copy absolute root folder to docker image ?

Answer (score 6):

Docker daemon runs within the context of the current directory. So you will need to copy the files to the directory from where your are running the Dockerfile.

Refer: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/4592

Answer (score 0):

If your Dockerfile is in the "Data" directory then I would write

...

```
RUN mkdir /data /data/resources

/resources/config /data/resources
```

You are making directory "data" (within the container) and then inside the "data" directory make "resources" directory.
In the second line you copy the local "resources" folder to the container "resources" folder.